# $lookup with pipe line not populating the data?

Tags: mongodb, mongoose, aggregation-framework

I have two schema as follow

```
const CoconutImportSchema = new Schema({
    userId: {
        type: Schema.Types.ObjectId,
        ref: 'User',
        required: true
    },
    farmerId: {
        type: Schema.Types.ObjectId,
        ref: 'Farmer'
    },
    settledOn: {
        type: Date,
        default: null
    },
    importedOn: {
        type: Date,
        default: Date.now()
    }

},
    { toJSON: { virtuals: true } }
)

const FMoneyTransactionSchema = new Schema({
    userId: {
        type: Schema.Types.ObjectId,
        ref: 'User',
        required: true
    },
    farmerId: {
        type: Schema.Types.ObjectId,
        ref: 'Farmer'
    },
    amount: {
        type: Number,
        required: true
    },
    date: {
        type: Date,
        default: Date.now()
    },
    settledOnImport: {
        type: Schema.Types.ObjectId,
        ref:'CoconutImport',
        default:null
    }
})
```

for every tranasaction in CoconutImport there may multiple records in Fmonetrasanction.If a transaction in FmoneyTransaction is settled then the _id of the import transaction will be present in settledOnImport field.

I got a usecase where i have to get the details of import and then from the collection FmoneyTransaction i have to get all unsettled transaction i.e., settledOnImport=null. I also have to popuplate the farmer details in the import

```
await CoconutImports.aggregate([
        {
            $match: {
                _id: Types.ObjectId(importId),
                userId: Types.ObjectId(userId)
            }

        },
        {
            $lookup: {
                from: FMoneyTransactions.collection.name,
                "let": {
                    "farmerId": "$farmerId"
                },
                pipeline: [
                    {
                        $match: {
                            $expr: {
                                $and: [

                                    {
                                        $eq: [
                                            "$$farmerId",
                                            "$farmerId"
                                        ]
                                    },
                                    {
                                        $eq: [
                                            "$settledOnImport", null
                                        ]
                                    }
                                ]

                            }
                        }

                    }
                ],
                as: "unsettledMoneyTransactions"
            }
        },
        {
            $lookup: {
                from: Farmer.collection.name,
                localField: 'farmerId',
                foreignField: '_id',
                as: 'farmerId'
            }
        },
```

this works but the following does not work

```
await CoconutImports.aggregate([
        {
            $match: {
                _id: Types.ObjectId(importId),
                userId: Types.ObjectId(userId)
            }

        },

        {
            $lookup: {
                from: Farmer.collection.name,
                localField: 'farmerId',
                foreignField: '_id',
                as: 'farmerId'
            },
        {
            $lookup: {
                from: FMoneyTransactions.collection.name,
                "let": {
                    "farmerId": "$farmerId._id"
                },
                pipeline: [
                    {
                        $match: {
                            $expr: {
                                $and: [

                                    {
                                        $eq: [
                                            "$$farmerId",
                                            "$farmerId"
                                        ]
                                    },
                                    {
                                        $eq: [
                                            "$settledOnImport", null
                                        ]
                                    }
                                ]

                            }
                        }

                    }
                ],
                as: "unsettledMoneyTransactions"
            }
        }
        }])
```

Can any one explain why?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based on provided `CoconutImportSchema`, `farmerId` is an `ObjectId`. In the first aggregation you reference it in your `"farmerId": "$farmerId"` statement and then you use it in your pipeline to compare it's equality against other `farmerId` field from  `FMoneyTransactions` collection. So it's **ObjectId against ObjectId** comparison. And it works.

In second provided aggregation you run `$lookup` on `Farmer` schema first. This [$lookup](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/lookup/index.html) overwrites existing `farmerId`. As `$lookup` always returns an **array**, after that step you're getting an array under `farmerId` field. Then when you try to define `"farmerId": "$farmerId._id"` it returns an array so in that step you're comparing **An array of ObjectIds** against **ObjectId**. Therefore you're getting no results.

To fix that you can run $unwind on `farmerId` after first `$lookup` if you're sure that it's one-to-one relationship between `CoconutImports` and `farmer`

```
await CoconutImports.aggregate([
    {
        $match: {
            _id: Types.ObjectId(importId),
            userId: Types.ObjectId(userId)
        }
    },
    {
        $lookup: {
            from: Farmer.collection.name,
            localField: 'farmerId',
            foreignField: '_id',
            as: 'farmerId'
        },
    },
    {   $unwind: "$farmerId" },
    {
        $lookup: {
            from: FMoneyTransactions.collection.name,
            "let": {
                "farmerId": "$farmerId._id"
            },
            pipeline: [
                {
                    $match: {
                        $expr: {
                            $and: [

                                {
                                    $eq: [
                                        "$$farmerId",
                                        "$farmerId"
                                    ]
                                },
                                {
                                    $eq: [
                                        "$settledOnImport", null
                                    ]
                                }
                            ]

                        }
                    }
                }
            ],
            as: "unsettledMoneyTransactions"
        }
    }
}])
```